# Any command in sbt shell induces `expected ';'` error

Tags: scala, sbt

I have tried to run any command in sbt shell for both terminal and Intellij Idea with the same result:

```
sbt:loom> println("Hello")
[error] Expected ';'
[error] println("Hello")
[error]                 ^
sbt:loom> println("Hello");
[error] Expected ';'
[error] println("Hello")
[error]                 ^
sbt:loom> val list = List.apply(1)
[error] Expected ';'
[error] val list = List.apply(1)
[error]                         ^
```

How can I run a command in sbt shell?

Comment: You can not execute scala code on an sbt shell. You can, however, open an scala shell inside the sbt shell using the `console` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`eval`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#General+commands) command to evaluate Scala expressions within sbt shell

```
sbt:foo> eval println("Hello")
Hello
[info] ans: Unit = null
sbt:foo> eval List.apply(1)
[info] ans: List[Int] = List(1)
```